# Deriving acceleration (time derivative of speed) at a position when speed is only given as function of position

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The background of my questions is physics, but I think the question itself is better suited for math.stackexchange.com.

#### Informal Description

Suppose you measure the speed of a train at many (all) positions $x$ along a track, but you forgot to record the time when it was at position $x$. Is it possible to compute the acceleration at every position $x$?

#### Attempt at a formalization

Lets call $s(t)$, $v(t)=ds(t)/dt$ and $a(t) = dv(t)/dt$ the position, speed and acceleration in dependency of time $t$. Further define as $\hat v(x) = v(s(t))$ and $\hat a(x) = a(s(t))$ the speed and acceleration depending on position (not time).

Given only $\hat v(x)$ for $x\in(0,l)$ for some $l$, can we derive $\hat a(x)$ or some of $s(t)$, $v(t)$ and $a(t)$ for a suitable interval of $t$.

#### Example

Suppose $\hat v(x) = 2+\sin(x)$ for $x\in (0,\pi)$, what would be, for example, $\hat a(1) = a(s(t_0))$ where $t_0$ is chosen such that $1 = s(t_0)$.

#### footnote

I tried already some combinations of the given functions with variable replacements and the inverse function of $s$ but cannot get it to work. It feels like it is either trivial or not possible at all.

### Edit

The attempt at formalization above is really just an attempt. Had I taken a look at the function types I would have noticed that $v(s(t))$ is nonsense. $v$ must be applied to time, not to position $s(t)$. Seeing the accepted answer I realized that it should be $\hat v(s(t)) = v(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acceleration is $\frac{dv}{dt}$ and, by the chain rule, this is $$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}.$$

Therefore all you need do to find the acceleration is multiply the velocity $v$ by $\frac{dv}{dx}$.

So, for your example, the acceleration is $(2+\sin(x))\cos(x)$.